# FireFox and IE render XSLT documents differently

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, firefox, xslt

I'm not an XML "expert", but I am trying to get there. I recently attempted to write my first transformation document and I thought it was going pretty well as evidenced by my beautiful result in IE...

When I attempted to verify like results in other browsers, though, it all fell apart. My guess is that I coded something improperly against the XSLT standard and IE guessed my intentions and displayed it.

Obviously I don't know what the problem is, but I have a couple guesses. My bet is that it has something to do with the DOCTYPE ENTITY I declared, probably deprecated or something, but IE still renders it. Based on what I think MIGHT be the problem, I'll include the file texts where I believe the issue lies, but if someone needs more information, I'm happy to include more details.

I didn't include the entire xslt for space sake, also I'm 99.9% sure that the problem is not with the xslt, but with one of the other 3 files I included in their entirety.

I'm sincerely thankful for any assistance in advance.

**`index.html`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=conf/contentNavMenu.xml">
  <title>SmartBook</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**`contentNavMenu.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../smartbook.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE smartbook [
  <!ENTITY navigationMenu SYSTEM "smartbookLinks.xml">
]>

<smartbook>
  <navMethod>JS</navMethod>
  &navigationMenu;
</smartbook>
```

**`smartbookLinks.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu>
  <menuItem>
    <id>1</id>
    <text>Problem Identification</text>
    <subMenu>
      <navalturl>navalt/1.html</navalturl>
      <menuItem>
        <id>1.1</id>
        <text>Identify a real world need.</text>
        <url></url>
        <target>_blank</target>
        <details>Details 1.1</details>
      </menuItem>
      <menuItem>
        <id>1.2</id>
        <text>Identify specific area of the identified need.</text>
        <url></url>
        <target>_blank</target>
        <details>Details 1.2</details>
      </menuItem>
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>
  <menuItem>
    <id>2</id>
    <text>Risk Identification and Mitigation</text>
    <subMenu>
      <navalturl>navalt/2.html</navalturl>
      <menuItem>
        <id>2.1</id>
        <text>Text 2.1</text>
        <url></url>
        <target>_blank</target>
        <details>Details 2.1</details>
      </menuItem>
    </subMenu>
  </menuItem>
</menu>
```

**`smartbook.xsl`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>

<head>  
  <link href="../css/smartbook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/sb_navigation.js"></script>
</head> 

<body style="margin-top:4px;">

    ...content omitted...

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Consider that the problem is most likely in the part marked "...content omitted..."  Also, you haven't given any hint about how it fails other than "it falls apart".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't load external entities. See [developer.mozilla.org/en/XML_in_Mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/XML_in_Mozilla) for details.

Comment: Ok, thanks DevNull for that resource. I've read it a number of times and while it states that external entities can't be loaded, it doesn't offer any advise to mitigate the scenario. Do you happen to have any advice on how to repair the code?

Thanks again!